# How do I use this IE10 Virtual Machine?

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, microsoft-virtual-pc, vhd, internet-explorer-10

I downloaded [this IE10 virtual machine](http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads) for windows 7 and I have managed to mount the VHD, but how do I actually get it to start? Do I need to also install virtual PC or some other software or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Download and install Windows Virtual PC.
2. Create a new VM.

   [image: 1]
3. When the wizard asks you about the new VM's hard disk, you can either choose to create a new VHD or point to an existing one. Obviously choose the latter.
4. Run your newly created VM and it will boot into Win7/Win8 (whichever image you downloaded). Use the login instructions from the modern.ie site and you can then start using IE10 as usual.

Comment: I didnt have Virtual PC installed but I have created the new VHD in windows disk management. What is the best approach now, I presume just install virtual PC and then??

Comment: Also completely confused about Virtual PC. Everything I see is for letting people run 7 in XP mode. Are there different versions of Virtual PC?

Comment: If you attach the VHD it'll simply show up as a new drive. One option is to run `bcdboot F:\Windows` from an elevated command prompt where F: is the VHD drive. This will add the VHD to the boot menu and should allow you to boot from it directly. But I would recommend installing VPC and filtering my instructions instead so you can access both host and guest OSes simultaneously. XP Mode is a VM that you need to download separately to use with VPC to have access to XP, but you can install your own copy of XP etc. in VPC add you please. Just download the latest version for Win7 and use it.

Comment: Thanks but I can't find the download link that I need

Comment: Try http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=282681

Comment: Ugh, sorry for the mistakes in my comment above. "filtering my instructions" = "following my instructions", "add you please" = "as you please". Stupid mobile text prediction!

Answer (score 0):

There is a Link on that Site called: [Download detailed requirements and instructions here](http://virtualization.modern.ie/vhd/virtualmachine_instructions.pdf)

Explained in more Detail [here](http://blog.reybango.com/2013/02/04/making-internet-explorer-testing-easier-with-new-ie-vms/)

Basically you install something like Oracle VirtualBox, Mount the Image and log into the virtual machine using your Host OS User/Pass

Hope this helps

Comment: I've read it and I'm going to read it again. I don't see where it's telling me how to get it started, only how to get it installed, which it is? Can you point out what I'm missing please?

Comment: Did you actually go through those instructions? As far as I can see that PDF doesn't tell you how to make use of the VHD. It assumes you already know that part. Also, link-only answers are poor form - you need to include more details in your answers.

Comment: I am not a fan of retyping everything that is already there...

Comment: I personally think the instructions on your first link http://virtualization.modern.ie/vhd/virtualmachine_instructions.pdf are only good enough for people who are already familiar with virtual machines and understand the concepts involved and are somewhat used to the terminology.

Comment: I'm not a fan of voting up answers that just contain links :-). That is what we expect out of answers though, the information, not just links